# how to set a object from another object inside lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am getting a list of managers from DB and now i have to populate each object of this list to another object i.e. employee and return it as a list (employeeList) to its calling function. Both Manager and Employee contains the same fields. I have to achieve this using lambda expression using stream.

Employee.java

```
public class Employee {
private String name;
private String designation;
private String active;

public String getActive() {
    return active;
}
public void setActive(String active) {
    this.active = active;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getDesignation() {
    return designation;
}
public void setDesignation(String designation) {
    this.designation = designation;
}}
```

Manager.java

```
public class Manager {
private String name;
private String designation;
private String active;
public String getActive() {
    return active;
}
public void setActive(String active) {
    this.active = active;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getDesignation() {
    return designation;
}
public void setDesignation(String designation) {
    this.designation = designation;
}}
```

ComponentImpl.java

```
public class ComponentImpl {

public List<Employee> catchAllEmployess () {

    List<Manager> managers = DbOperation.collectManagers(2);
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Manager manager : managers) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setName(manager.getName());
        employee.setDesignation(manager.getDesignation());
        employee.setActive(manager.getActive());
        employees.add(employee);
    }
    return employees;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the expression by including a constructor in Employee class as

```
Employee(String name, String designation, String active) {
        this.name = name;
        this.designation = designation;
        this.active = active;
    }
```

which can then be used as

```
List<Employee> employees = managers.stream()
                .map(manager -> new Employee(manager.getName(), manager.getDesignation(), manager.getActive()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: great this will work but what if employee class has more fields, let say 30 field and where making a parameterized constructor is not a reliable option?

Comment: well, ideally the design approach with the problem statement shared by you was something I didn't dig into and having those many fields in say both Manager and Employee classes and assigning them to one while iterating on another anyway is a bad choice of implementation IMHO.

Comment: I was just curious about how it can be done without using constructor.. not specific to above problem let consider we have two object which has different fields but i want some specific field to be set inside lambda expression

Comment: @AnandKumar A better approach to me then looks to be using a utility which does such conversion(setting value from one object to fields of another object) and then referencing that within the stream to map a list of one type of object to another.

Comment: Okay, it will be very helpful if you can provide some reference or example. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously a contrived example so this answer might not be applicable, but the way these classes are written screams to me that either `Manager` should extend `Employee` or they should at least extend a common interface. Then the whole operation might not even be necessary anymore.

Comment: indeed, the way these classes almost look alike, there should be some relation between them.

Comment: I used above program as a example, i didn't know you guys will go that much deep in design structure. Sorry my mistake.

Comment: Yes, that was clear. But still it seems like if your real classes are really that closely related (which they might not be), than one might not need to convert between them in the first place.

Comment: True I totally agree, but i am just curious is it possible to implement without using constructor considering both the object are different (in terms of field name and number-can have extra fields) ? and what if the class has lots of field where i don't want to use constructor, instead i want to use setter for setting only the specific field that i want.

Comment: What I'd do in that case is to extract the conversion into a method `Employee makeEmployee(Manager manager)` and then use `map` with a reference to that method.